# Visual Studio Code cannot recognise Microsoft Build tools

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code, output, ionide

I am having difficulty using Ionide on Visual Studio code, after following tutorials and reinstalling to no avail, one problem still persists - this is that Visual Studio Code cannot find Microsoft Build tools 2013 - I have both the extension and the zip on Microsofts website installed.

edit: when attempting to run f# in VScode I am prompted to install MS build tools 2013

Any ideas people?

Many thanks,

Elliot

Comment: Do you mean MS build tools 2015? I didn't think that Ionide had MS Build tools 2013 dependency.

Comment: I was thinking that MS build tools 2015 would be more appropriate, but I keep getting prompted for specifically for the 2013 version - weird.

Comment: yeah, i have msbuild 12 (this is 2013), 14, 15, all installed so difficult to say. it certainly will need msbuild 15 (vs 2017), as it uses the new SDK.

Comment: Installed MS Build Tools 2015 and the FSI in Visual Studio Code works perfectly now!

Many thanks,


Elliot